# Is there any API method in Forge/Bim360 for filtering (pdf) documents/files by text content (full text search)?

Tags: autodesk-bim360

I currently developing a BIM360 integration and wonder if it is possible to filter requested files (PDFs actually) by text content. Had thoroughly went through BIM360/Forge API Specs but found nothing about filtering by content.

Comment: If you mean by pdf document title, that would be possible with Search API : https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/ , but if you mean by 'text within pdf doc', unfortunately, there is not such ability with BIM360 or Forge API.

Comment: Thank you, @XiaodongLiang, actually I mean 'text within pdf doc'. It's a pity that BIM360/Forge APIs don't have such ability.